# How to sort the data on ng-click() inside nested ng-repeat for multiple fields?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, multidimensional-array

How to sort the nested array below in ascending and descending order based on  angular `click()` function for address, price and time individually.

What I need is by default it must be sorted by price  ascending order and on `click()` other properties such as address, price and time should sort in ascending and descending order.
Any Help would me much appreciated.

#### Code:

```js
var app = angular.module('aaa',[]); // snippet

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myData = [{
      lstjourney: {
        0: {
          lstit: {
            0: {
              address: 'mumbai',
              price: 9255,
              time: '10-nov-2018 08:54:19 am'
            },


          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      lstjourney: {
        0: {
          lstit: {
            0: {
              address: 'Vikroli',
              price: 4556,
              time: '04-nov-2018 08:54:19 am'
            },


          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      lstjourney: {
        0: {
          lstit: {
            0: {
              address: 'Hyderabad',
              price: 5896,
              time: '10-nov-2018 08:54:19 am'
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

  ];

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script> <!-- snippet -->

<div ng-app="aaa" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-click="SortFun('price')">price</li>
    <li ng-click="SortFun('time')">time</li>
    <li ng-click="SortFun('address')">address</li>
  </ul>
  <div ng-repeat="(names,itemR) in myData ">
    <div ng-repeat="(name,item) in itemR.lstjourney ">
      {{item.lstit[0].price}}---{{item.lstit[0].time}}-- {{item.lstit[0].address}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: JavaScript has `.sort` method on arrays, which can [sort by object property values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-javascript-object-by-property-value)

Answer (score 0):

in angular you can use filters inside ´ng-repeat´